# CCAnimate error after declaring NSMutable array and animation in init

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm having an error that i don't know how to solve, I've declared an NSMutablearray in my init, filled it with two sprites to animate, and declare the CCAnimation;

```
        animParpadeoNina =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [animParpadeoNina addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"ninaCamina002b.png"]];
    [animParpadeoNina addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"ninaCamina002.png"]];
    for (id obj in animParpadeoNina) {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    }

    paralanina = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animParpadeoNina delay:.2];
```

Now, if i call the action just after declare it all, the animation works, but if i try to run the CCAnimation in any other function, I get " EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0xb0ab1de8)

If i fill the array AND declare the CCAnimation inside the function, then it works. The thing is that i want to run this action several times, and it doesn't feels the right way to fill and declare once and once again the same code...

What am i doing wrong? Any suggestion to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: animParpadeoNina =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

```
animParpadeoNina =  [NSMutableArray alloc];
```

This should be:

```
animParpadeoNina =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Wops... my error!. This is one of the tries i did. Just edit the code, i use "animParpadeoNina =  [NSMutableArray array];" The other line with alloc was a try to fix the trouble... that unfortunately didn't work for me.